# How to correctly print a string passed as an argument to a Bash function?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm writing shell(bash) script like this:

```
output_function()
{
    for i in "$@"
    do
        echo $i
    done
}

process_funtion()
{
    string=process some thing
    output_function $string
}
```

for example, after process some thing, string is

```
i am line 1
i am line 2
```

I want to print these 2 line as it is, but actually I got

```
i
am
line
1
i
am
line
2
```

Also this NOT work:

```
#!/bin/bash

output()
{
    printf '%s\n' "$@"
}

output `ifconfig`
```

result is:

```
...
2000
inet6
fe80::6de5:743c:addd:7c5a%utun0
prefixlen
64
scopeid
0xa
nd6
options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
```

And this NOT work also:

```
#!/bin/bash

output()
{
    printf '%s\n' "$*"
}

output `ifconfig`
```

result is all in one line.

how to fix this? thank you~

Comment: The "$@" is a special variable that creates a *list* of parameters that are separated by spaces. I think $* may do what you want or remove the quotes and use $@.

Comment: No, both $@ and $* does NOT work.

Comment: First `output` and `output_function` are not the same name. Assuming that's fixed, `for i in "$*"` (doublequotes and dollar-asterisk) will put all the passed arguments into one value, hence one `echo` and one line. But the passed arguments from `output $string` have already had all whitespace (particularly newlines) reduced to a single space, and any wildcards expanded (or dropped, if unmatched with `nullglob` set), so this is not 'as is'. You probably want `output "$line"` and `output(){ echo "$1"; }` (dollar-one)

Comment: `printf '%s\n' "$@"` and then call `output "$(ifconfig)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example:

```
output()
{
    printf '%s\n' "$*"
}

output `ifconfig`
```

the result of ifconfig also needs to be quoted, otherwise the result will be split into multiple arguments (using $IFS) before being passed to the function. So

```
output "`ifconfig`"
```

should do.

See [Bash Reference Manual: 3.4.2 Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters-1) for using `$*` and `$@` correctly and the difference between both.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose the function arguments in double quotes to prevent [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting):

```
output "$string"
```

instead of

```
output $string
```

And you don't really need a loop to print the contents of `$@`, you could simply write:

```
printf '%s\n' "$@"
```

---

See also:

- [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)
- [Word Splitting - Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html)

Comment: Similarly, if you do use `echo`, use `echo "$i"` instead of `echo $i`. Having variable references occur outside of double-quotes is usually a mistake. (There are some situations where it's ok, but IMO keeping track of them is more trouble than it's worth -- just use double-quotes and don't worry about it.)

Comment: That NOT work under bash-3.2, refer to the result I post above.

Comment: @batmancn It does work under bash-3.2 -- did you use `output "$(ifconfig)"`?